# Temporarly Prevent Forced Sleep on Mac OS X through Python/Terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, sleep

How can one disable *forced* sleep (sleep caused by the user - often by closing lid/pressing Sleep under the apple menu) through Terminal, preferably with a Python script, on OS X?  I would like to be able to run the following or similiar...

```
import os
cmd = """ *?*Sleep Disable Command*?* """
def fullVolume():
     os.system(cmd)

while True:
    fullVolume()
```

...to accomplish said task.

I have done a fair share of research, and I couldn't find much, bar this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html

And this:
https://code.google.com/p/macosx-nosleep-extension/
https://github.com/integralpro/nosleep/releases

I believe there may be some way to incorporate code from the NoSleep extension into this script, but I am quite unsure on how to do so.  Help is much appreciated! =)

Comment: Do you mean this? `pmset noidle`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That command only prevents "idle" sleep - I need to prevent "forced" sleep.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. From Apple docs: "...even with I/O Kit, it is not possible to prevent forced sleep, only delay it."
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to sleep'
```

~

```
str1='tell application "System Events" to sleep'
os.system("osascript -e '"+ str1+ "'")
```

Comment: I think this *causes* a sleep, whereas the OP wants to *avoid* sleeping.